# How often does a Rollup field on an entity recalculate?

Tags: dynamics-crm

Yep RTFM right? Too bad it's not clear like all FMs... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/customize/define-rollup-fields

Anyone who can make sense of the "Mass Calculate Rollup Field" job vs the "Calculate Rollup Field" job? And the timing of each?

I understand the documentation to mean:

- There will be 1 initial/first calculation 12 hours after a field is created
- Then, there will be a recurring job every 1 hour

Yet many articles online spout "every 12 hours!" which seems wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try my best to summarize them.

——
**Mass Calculate Rollup Field** - Async job to do bulk calculation in existing records without impacting business

**Purpose**: Bulk updates of each Rollup field in existing entity records
**Scope**: Per Rollup field in an entity
**Recurrence**: Not really a recurring job
**Default first run schedule**: 12 hours after create/update of a Rollup field
**Next run**: After first run it will be postponed to run after 10 years unless there’s an update in the formula of that Rollup field

——

**Calculate Rollup Field** - Async job to calculate all the Rollup fields in a particular entity on a timely fashion. Only delta updates after last run or manual force calculation.

**Purpose**: Timely calculation to existing entity records
**Scope**: Per entity for all Rollup fields
**Recurrence**: Yes, a recurring job every hour or Admin defined schedule
**Default first run schedule**: 1 hour after last run of Bulk Rollup field job or last run of this same Async job

——

Third one is user triggered ie manual Adhoc recalculation on each field on CRM record form.

Comment: Arun you've helped me multiple times before, and it's much appreciated. I wonder if you could check out another puzzler of mine? :)  
      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62961394/crm-managed-solution-will-uninstalling-remove-every-custom-field