# CRM Managed Solution - will Uninstalling remove every custom field?

Tags: dynamics-crm

Here's what happened:

- We downloaded a managed solution from a 3rd party.
- In the .zip, we can clearly see it only specifies 2 new fields for Account
- HOWEVER after importing into CRM... when in CRM we open and look at the managed solution... it shows every single field for Account! Not just the new ones from the zip
- We'd like to uninstall the managed solution, and only remove the 2 new Account fields
- BUT... the managed solution in CRM now shows every single custom field on Account. Will we lose those too if we delete? Or is it normal for managed solutions when viewed in CRM to show every field for the entity, and we can safely assume only those we saw in the .zip will be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From top of my head I could not recollect from my experience why the managed solution showing your custom fields or is it intended.

Though it should not remove any of your custom components when you’re deleting/uninstalling the third party managed solution, I cannot comment on any third party about perfection.

I would recommend you to do a dry run by installing the managed solution in any sandbox environment and testing yourself by deleting it. This way you can be sure.

Typical managed solution should not remove any of our customization when uninstalled. They should only wipe out their components.

Comment: Arun I really appreciate your answers and comments. Can you please take a look at another CRM Solution-related question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68279790/importing-my-unmanaged-solution-does-not-change-the-account-form