# Importing my Unmanaged Solution does not change the Account form

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a customized Account "Main" Form in CRM.

I added a new tab, a new section, and new fields inside it.

I published all customizations before-hand, then export, then import into my test environment. I publish all in the test environment.

The Unmanaged Solution contains this form and its new fields; When I review the Form XML in the exported zip's customizations.xml file, it indeed has the new tab label, new section label, I can see the fields in the XML.

**PROBLEM**: But after importing and publishing into the test environment... the changes don't show up!

What I see in its place is the way that section looked BEFORE (not sure how long ago last time it was changed). It's simply not getting my latest changes.

**How can an Unmanaged solution import have these issues? What else is there to check/consider?** I don't think Solution Layers would cause this since it's Unmanaged, nothing stood out there anyway.

Comment: I would investigate if you are looking at the same forms btw the orgs? Did you verify the form in editor rather from UI / app in target environment ?

Comment: Have you tried to publish the customization ? not the new solution you added recently

Comment: @ArunVinoth-MVP since you rock, can you check out this other CRM question? Just looking for best practice explanation/suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70236409/ootb-security-roles-if-we-change-them-to-our-needs-do-the-changes-get-undone

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this check list, also *note** with Dynamics it needs more env/info including your environment to trouble shoot, since it could be something in tandem with your env.

---

### 1. Usual Suspects in an *UnManaged* Solution

> With yours being an `UNMANAGED` solution, I strongly suspect its a `security permissions issue` ***not setup/enabled in the Target environment***, check your logs, you may see something like this
> [image: Dynamics CRM does not show new form fields due to security and permissions]

```
Try these Solution Importing steps
```

> 1. Import your main solution (note* without field security profiles).
> 2. Now, Publish all your customizations (note* you can enable/import the field security after this step)
> 3. Lastly, Import the second solution which would contain your field security profiles

---

### 2. Troubleshooting Checklist

```
 To resolve/hunt down the issue, try these checklist steps
```

- **Check IIS**: if you reset/restart IIS, (after define and publish your field)
- **Clear you client side cache**: run it by
  pressing Ctrl+F5
- **Clear you server side cache**:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/portals/admin/clear-server-side-cache
- **Are using the entity form**:
- **Do you have the correct**: `entity permissions` `Notes` & `Sub Grid`
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/portals/configure-notes
- **Did you add** the `metadata`
- Lastly **are you using activities**

  [image: Dynamics CRM Activities Tab]

Comment: In that documentation link, do you have any idea what URL they're referring to when they say `<portal_path>/_services/about`? A simple example? I don't know what portal_path is supposed to be for my CRM online instance.