# OOTB Security Roles - if we change them to our needs, do the changes get undone by Microsoft updates?

Tags: dynamics-crm

Should we avoid modifying OOTB roles, is this an unsafe practice?

If we cannot change them reliably, then is the best practice to make a copy with your ORG/company prefix and then modify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the practices I learned at the company I worked at early in my Dynamics career (~2008), I always copy the OOB roles and modify the copies.

Here are some reasons for this:

1. Once you edit the roles if you ever decided you want them back to the default, it could be a pain to restore them. If you are going to edit them, before you touch them you might want to put the originals in a solution and export that solution.
2. Editing a role can diminish its value as a template for new roles. If you leave them as is, you and anyone else who does security customizations start from the same place.
3. Although I'm not sure it has ever happened, a Microsoft update could theoretically modify the OOB roles.

Comment: Thanks for sharing Aron. That makes some sense to me. Do you recall/know why that's the suggested approach? I guess pros and cons I'm wondering, trying to convince myself one way or the other :)

Comment: You're welcome. Updated the answer with more info. If I think of any additional reasons, I'll add them.